# Select a specific number in a number

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a number say 123456. Each of these digits means something individually to me. I would like to be able to select say the fourth digit in this string of numbers (4) and assign it to variable.

My question is how would I go about doing this in mvc?

Comment: How is this related to MVC though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int number = 123456;

int fourth = number.ToString()[3];
```

Is this what you want?

Of course, it goes without saying that `number` has to have at least 4 digits.

Comment: char FourthChar = NumberString[3];
int CheckDigit = FourthChar - '0';

Comment: Does this seem a little convoluted or is there a cleaner way of achieving the same result

Answer (score 0):

Why not just convert it to a string and pull out the n-th character?

It'll be slower than some other methods, but I'm sure you and anyone else reading that piece of code will know *exactly* what it does.

Assuming you want to do this server-side:

```
int n = {the index of the digit you're intersted in};
int theNumber = 1233456;
char theDigit = theNumber.ToString()[n];
```

If you need to do this client-side in javascript you can do the following:

```
n = {the index of the digit you're interseted in};
theNumber = 123456;
digit = (theNumber + "")[n];
```